# One more query about setting up web pages to print on Android

Tags: php, android, html, printing-web-page

I have several scrolling web pages that print to pdf easily on computers or iPhone using Chrome and simple print commands.  On Android, only a screen shot is displayed for printing so the bottom portions of the pages are not printed to pdf.  However, on the same android devices with the same (default) print commands, a full, multiple-page pdf is printed from many popular websites, like wsj.com for example.  Is it possible, with simple html, php or style commands within a web page to create more than a screen shot when printing web pages on android? I can't send the pages to 3rd party software because the pages are dynamic and created within sessions behind password protection. I've spent days researching this on stack overflow and am now prepared to be humiliated!

Comment: Are you sure they use *same (default) print commands*?
Also, which commands are you using?
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Great. Thanks for responding.  I use print preview with IE, print with Chrome. With IPhone, the embedded print command works. With Android, I was using print or share->print (depending on the device manufacturer). These only print/display the first page and that's the crux of my problem.  On wsj.com, these print commands on android show the whole 30 or so pages.  I can also use window.print inside a button for the PCs with the same results. I'm not worrying about formatting at the moment on the Androids.  I need to capture all the information first before going down that rabbit hole. Rex

Comment: Shirkam: I could mock up an html page that prints all the information on PCs using the embedded print commands but only the first 60 lines or so on Android if that would bring better focus to my question.  I could put this page on the web for us to modify in various ways.

Comment: Hey Shirkam and the rest of the universe.  This is fantastic.  In the process of setting up a dummy site, I got window.print to work on all of the devices. In other words, I have, in my own clumsy way, routed around the problem that the default print queries are somewhat inconsistent.  So, I can move forward.  In the end, I benefitted a lot by making a fool of myself.  Thanks to all for listening.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to include all that info, and make an answer yourself with your solution, so other people with the same problem can easily find a solution.